# Starting uwsgi with systemd fails -

Tags: linux, uwsgi, systemd, boot, systemctl

I run my code on a raspberry pi 4 wit Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
.
I want to start my uwsgi server via systemd.
My .ini file:

```
http = :5000
processes = 4
threads = 2
wsgi-file = /home/pi/Python/uwsgi_examples/hello_flask.py
callable = app
```

The app is a simple flask application.
My my_service.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=uwsgi Service
After=network.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/.local/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/pi/Python/uwsgi_examples/flask.ini
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT

[Install]
WantedBy=multi.user.target
```

When I run:

```
sudo systenctl start my_service.service
```

all works fine but after a reboot the sever is not running. (I enabled my service) When I run:

```
sudo systemctl status my_service
```

I get the following feedback:

```
my_service.service - uwsgi Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my_service.service; enabled; vendor pr>
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my mistake.
I had a typo in the .sevice file.
After correcting

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi.user.target
```

to

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

the server starts at reboot